# A very simple Tic tac toe app, cant get it to print the winner in the system, where am I missing out?

Tags: java, android

## I was learning this through Udemy course, but this Code has not been working.the System.out.println gives no output.

-The only problem is I am not getting no output.
-Everything else works fine.

package com.example.android.connectthree;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int activePlayer = 0;
    int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
    int[][] winningPositions = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};

    public void dropIn(View view) {
        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());
        if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2) {
            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

            counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);
            if (activePlayer == 0) {

                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);

                activePlayer = 1;
            } else {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
            counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);
            for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                        gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                        gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {
                    System.out.println(gameState[winningPosition[0]]);
                }
                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try logging the output using `Log.i` and see if you can see the output in the logger

Comment: It worked later on, Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to view anything you try to print with a System.out.println()? If so, which lines does does it print at?

It appears as though others who wrote this program have finished it slightly differently and output the result in a different way as seen at the following snippet:
https://codegists.com/snippet/java/mainactivityjava_demhaxee_java